# Dynamically replacing file content

Tags: powershell, replace

I have to read one properties file (let's say `prop.txt`) and update it dynamically.

Content looks like this.

```
server.names=xyz[500],server2[500],test[500]
```

I wanted to replace the content anything after `server.names=` with correct values, e.g.:

```
server1.company.com[500],server2.company.com[500],server3.company.com[500]
```

I tried below command but it is replacing `server.names=`.  I want to replace the values of `server.names=`

```
(Get-Content $path).Replace("server.names=",$NewServerNames) | Set-Content $path
```

Any idea how to replace the value of `server.names=`?

Comment: (Get-Content $path).Replace("server.names=",$NewServerNames) | Set-Content $path   ... This is replaceing "server.names=", which is not what i want.

Comment: Good to know, please [edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48524854/edit) and explain how it failed to solve your problem

Comment: So you're trying to replace the server names with their FQDN?  That's what it looks like.

Comment: Yes. When i install the product i'm getting sample values in properties file. Now i'm replacing sample values with exact server names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but your syntax is off.  This solution utilizes regex to capture the original key:

```
$Pattern = 'server\.names='

Get-Content -Path $Path |
    ForEach-Object {
        If ($_ -match $Pattern)
        {
            $_ -replace "($Pattern).*","$1$NewServerNames"
        }
        Else
        {
            $_
        }
    } |
    Set-Content -Path $Path
```

Comment: I changed little bit and it is working as expected..............                        
 (Get-Content -Path $Path) -replace '(server\.names=).*',"server.names=$1$NewServerNames" | Set-Content -Path $Path

Comment: That's not going to work how you think it will @jks. `$1` is a backreference to the capture group so you're copying the same text twice.

Comment: If i'm not adding server.names infront of replacing string, i only see server names but not server.names= server names. Not quite sure how backreference value getting missed